# Angular.js web app through Sails.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, sails.js

I am developing a web application using Sailsjs for the backend and Angular.js for the front end. To scaffold the Angular app I have used yeoman with the angular generator and for the back end I used the default Sails app generator.

During development I run 2 servers, the 1st is the sails server to host the back end and the second a grunt server for the front end.

For now my configuration works fine but when in production I want to combine the two ends in one and have sails server serve the angular web app...

Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: how about using this generator: https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-sails-angular?

Comment: I have seen that one but I am hesitant to use it because, as mentioned in the docs "Grunt live-reload, server, test do not work."  and I really like live reload.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS + SailsJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938850/angularjs-sailsjs)

Comment: I have seen that thread but could not make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Sails before but it looks like it generates an assets directory. If you'll notice, Yeoman created an "app" directory into which it put the index.html, JavaScript, styles, etc. It appears you could transfer the contents of the Yeoman "app" directory to the Sail "assets" directory and it would be served up.

http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Assets

If no one with specific experience with Sails shows up, maybe that will help some.