# React + Sails : Handling Routes

Tags: reactjs, sails.js

I'm developing a web application using Sails and React. My main purpose of using sails is take advantage of MVC pattern, while React for serving views. Since, Sails provides it own routing, but I want to make use of my React-router instead.

For ex : In react-router we have `NotFoundRoute`, so when I'm accessing a page which is not present, it should show me the handler that I have defined for `NotFoundRoute`. Instead, it is showing me the sails 404 page.

So how to get control over the sails route when I want to use my React route?

**React Routes**

```
var JSX = require('babel/register'),
    React = require('react'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute,
    NotFoundRoute = Router.NotFoundRoute,
    Route = Router.Route;


var routes = (
        <Route name="splash" path="/" handler={require('../main')}>
            <DefaultRoute handler={require('../components/Signup/signup')} />   
            <Route name="signup" path="/user/signup" handler={require('../components/Signup/signup')} />    
            <Route name="home" path="/user/home/:id" handler={require('../components/Home/home')} />
            <NotFoundRoute handler={require('../components/commons/notFound')} />
        </Route>
    );

module.exports = routes;
```

**Sails Routes**

```
module.exports.routes = {


  '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },

  '/user/home/:id' : 'UserController.home'


};
```

I'm totally new to this frameworks and not able to find enough resources online..So sorry this silly question.

Comment: Show your Sails router code. The likely problem is that you haven't told Sails to serve **all** (wildcard) requests from the `index.html` of your React app.

Comment: @elithrar As you asked, I have added my sails routes. Pls let me know..what modification do I need to do.

Comment: See http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes - use a wildcard route - `/*` - *AFTER* your `UserController` route.

Comment: What about isomorphic routes ?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },
  '/user/home/:id' : 'UserController.home'
  '/*' : 'ReactApp.home'
};
```

you need to make a **wildcard** route that renders the react app whenever api routes are missing. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951751/2377491

1. Create a new Sails app with sails new mySailsApp
2. Wipe out the contents of the mySailsApp/assets folder
3. Copy the contents of myReactApp/dist folder into mySailsApp/assets
4. Replace the contents of mySailsapp/views/layout.ejs with those of the myReactApp/dist/index.html file
5. Cut all of the non-script tag content from the layout.ejs file (everything after the `<body>` tag and before the first `<script>` tag and use it to replace the contents of mySailsApp/views/homepage.ejs
6. Place `<%-body%>` after the `<body>` tag in layout.ejs

In your config/routes.js, put:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/*': {
    view: 'homepage',
    skipAssets: true
  }
}
```

You can then start the server with sails lift and you'll see the React app at http://localhost:1337.

Comment: If you have already other routes for your API, you have to add to the new route this attribute: skipRegex: /^\/api\/.*$/

Answer (score 0):

While this is an older question, it is still relevant nearly 5 years later.

I recently open-sourced a base configuration of [Sails/React/Bootstrap/Webpack](https://github.com/neonexus/sails-react-bootstrap-webpack), which could be useful to anyone that may stumble upon this question.